# Replace template tags with velocity using regex in java

Tags: regex, templates, tags, velocity

I need to replace some custom template tags in an HTML document with Velocity code, so that the output can be used in another application.

The code I receive looks like this:

```
<BG SWITCH>param
    <BG CASE>value1:
        text 1
    <BG /CASE>
    <BG CASE>value2:
        text 2
    <BG /CASE>
    <BG CASE>value3:
        text 3
    <BG /CASE>
    <BG CASE>value4:
        text 4
    <BG /CASE>
<BG /SWITCH>
```

And the result should look like this:

```
#set ($param = $!user.data.param)
#if($!param == "value1")
    text 1
#end
#if($!param == "value2")
    text 2
#end
#if($!param == "value3")
    text 3
#end
#if($!param == "value4")
    text 4
#end
```

The Java code I have until now is this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<BG SWITCH>(.+?)<BG CASE>(.+?):(.+?)<BG /CASE>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(newHtml);
newHtml = matcher.replaceAll("#set \\(\\$$1\\ = \\$!user.data.$1) #if(\\$$1 == \"$2\")$3 #end");
```

And the result I'm getting with that is this:

```
#set ($param = $!user.data.param)
    #if($param == "value1")
        text 1
    #end
    <BG CASE>value2:
        text 2
    <BG /CASE>
    <BG CASE>value3:
        text 3
    <BG /CASE>
    <BG CASE>value4:
        text 4
    <BG /CASE>
<BG /SWITCH>
```

So the "switch" and the first "case" get replaced correctly, but I don't know how to get the following cases replaced.

Any ideas?

#### EDIT after answer from svasa:

The proposed solution works great for the example code I provided, but I should have mentioned that that was only a snippet from the actual file to be processed. The actual file may contain multiple such switch-case blocks. In that case the proposed code doesn't quite cover it.

When the "source" looks like this:

```
<div>
    Some other content before
</div>

<div>
    <BG SWITCH>param1
        <BG CASE>value1:
            text 1
        <BG /CASE>
        <BG CASE>value2:
            text 2
        <BG /CASE>
        <BG CASE>value3:
            text 3
        <BG /CASE>
        <BG CASE>value4:
            text 4
        <BG /CASE>
    <BG /SWITCH>
</div>

<div>
    Some other content between
</div>

<div>
    <BG SWITCH>param2
        <BG CASE>value1:
            text 1
        <BG /CASE>
        <BG CASE>value2:
            text 2
        <BG /CASE>
        <BG CASE>value3:
            text 3
        <BG /CASE>
        <BG CASE>value4:
            text 4
        <BG /CASE>
    <BG /SWITCH>
</div>

<div>
    Some other content after
</div>
```

Then I get the following result:

```
#set ($param1 = $!user.data.param1)
#if($!param1== "value1")
    text 1
#end
#if($!param1== "value2")
    text 2
#end
#if($!param1== "value3")
    text 3
#end
#if($!param1== "value4")
    text 4
#end
#if($!param1== "value1")
    text 1
#end
#if($!param1== "value2")
    text 2
#end
#if($!param1== "value3")
    text 3
#end
#if($!param1== "value4")
    text 4
#end
```

So any other content before, between and after the switch-case blocks is lost, and the first "param" is used for second switch-case block. How would I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Before proceeding to look into the solution I wrote below - Your input
>   string looks more like an xml but it is not, because the strings like 
>   `BG /SWITCH` is not valid xml. Do you know this is correct input for you ?
>   All other elements and the structure of the string looks like xml.
>   Confirm with the source that it is an xml or not. If it is an xml, it
>   is a breeze to extract whatever you want with Java's inbuilt
>   [xpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).Otherwise it is excruciatingly painful to extract desired strings with regex as I did below for you.

Steps :

1. First get the desired `<div>` using the regex :

   `(<BG SWITCH>(.*)\\n\\s*(\\s*<BG CASE>(.*):\\n\\s*(.*)\\n\\s*<BG \\/CASE>)+\\n\\s*<BG \\/SWITCH>)`

Demo for this regex is [here](https://regex101.com/r/qG1xB5/1)

2. Pass those found strings to the regex I used in earlier answer:

I would go about getting the top line first i.e. `param` and then the remaining strings `value1:` , `text 1` etc.

For the `param` the regex would be : `<BG SWITCH>(.*)`

For the `value`, `text` strings you could use regex :

`<BG CASE>(.*)\\n?(\\s+(.*))\\n?\\s+<BG /CASE>`
Demo of this regex is [here](https://regex101.com/r/oO7hV0/2)

The code will look like :

```
String mainRegex = "(<BG SWITCH>(.*)\\n\\s*(\\s*<BG CASE>(.*):\\n\\s*(.*)\\n\\s*<BG \\/CASE>)+\\n\\s*<BG \\/SWITCH>)";
String result = "";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( mainRegex );
Matcher m = p.matcher( sb.toString() );
while ( m.find() )
{
    String toSearch = m.group();
    result += updateResult( result, toSearch );
}

System.out.println(result);


private static String updateResult( String replaced, String searchString )
{
     Pattern firstPattern = Pattern.compile("<BG SWITCH>(.*)");
     Matcher matcher = firstPattern.matcher(searchString);
     if ( matcher.find() )
     {
         String paramtext = matcher.group(1);

          replaced = "#set ($" + paramtext + " = $!user.data." + paramtext + ")";
          replaced = replaced + "\n";

          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<BG CASE>(.*):\\n?(\\s+(.*))\\n?\\s+<BG /CASE>");
          matcher = pattern.matcher(searchString);
          while ( matcher.find() )
          {
             String valueString = matcher.group(1);
             String textString = matcher.group(2);
             replaced = replaced + "#if($!" + paramtext  + "== \"" + valueString + "\")" + "\n" + textString + "\n#end" + "\n";
          }



     }

     return replaced;
}
```

Output from last `println` statement :

```
    #set ($param1 = $!user.data.param1)
#if($!param1== "value1")
            text 1
#end
#if($!param1== "value2")
            text 2
#end
#if($!param1== "value3")
            text 3
#end
#if($!param1== "value4")
            text 4
#end
#set ($param2 = $!user.data.param2)
#if($!param2== "value1")
            text 1
#end
#if($!param2== "value2")
            text 2
#end
#if($!param2== "value3")
            text 3
#end
#if($!param2== "value4")
            text 4
#end
```

Comment: Perfect, that's it, does exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot svasa! I wouldn't have gotten to that solution myself.

Comment: Hi @svasa, I edited my original question. It would be really great if you could have another look at it, because it turns out I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: @David are you receiving this in a file or in a string ?

Comment: Hi @svasa, the people who will use the application will have an html file, and for now they'll just open it in a text editor, copy-paste the code into a form, and my JSP application will convert the code and return it. Once it works I'd add a file upload or something, but for now I'm working with the String from an HTML textarea. Would that make a difference in how to process it with the Regexes?

Comment: @David Edited the answer. Have a look

Comment: thanks again for your effort, @svasa! As I'm not at work anymore, I'll try this out first thing tomorrow. But by reading the code, It looks like the "content before / between / after" and the divs surrounding the switch-case blocks are still lost, right? Could I keep those with extra capturing groups? Regarding your question/remark about the code being XML or not: no it's not, unfortunately. The code comes from some CMS. The closing tags for example look like this: <BG /CASE>. For it being valid XML it would have to look like this <BGCASE>...</BGCASE>. So xpath won't work for me I'm afraid.

Comment: do you need those extra `div`s ? I thought you are only interested in `value`, `text` strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121199/discussion-between-david-and-svasa).